# p5.js: How could this code be simplified into a 'for' loop?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that is using p5.js. How could I simplify this into a 'for' loop that uses an array?

[The code I want simplified.](https://jsfiddle.net/j450aq1d/)

What I already tried and didn't work:

```
   var colorDiv = [redDiv, orangeDiv, yellowDiv, yellowGreenDiv, greenDiv, turquoiseDiv, cyanDiv, cobaltDiv, blueDiv, violetDiv, magentaDiv, crimsonDiv, blackDiv, whiteDiv, brownDiv, lightGreyDiv, darkGreyDiv];

var colorRGB = ["rgb(255,0,0)", "rgb(255,125,0)", "rgb(255,255,0)", "rgb(125,255,0)", "rgb(0,255,0)", "rgb(0,255,125)", "rgb(0,255,255)", "rgb(0,125,255)", "rgb(0,0,255)", "rgb(125,0,255)", "rgb(255,0,255)", "rgb(255,0,125)", "rgb(0,0,0)", "rgb(255,255,255)", "rgb(114, 64, 25)", "rgb(175,175,175)", "rgb(110,110,110)"]; ]

for (var i = colorDiv.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var string = String(colorDiv[i]);
    string = string.replace("Div", "");
    var colorDiv[i] = createDiv(string); // Red
    colorDiv[i].id();
    colorDiv[i].style("width", "30px");
    colorDiv[i].style("height", "30px");
    colorDiv[i].style("background-color", "" + colorRGB[i]);
}
```

Comment: I do not get what you want to do ? Please help to explain more. As I see, you still used for loop for that case.

Comment: The code I tried to simplify is in the jsfiddle. The for loop is my attempt to simplify it, but it did not work.